# HTML inside a PHP variable without losing syntax highlight

Tags: php, html, syntax-highlighting

I have some large HTML code that I want to put in a PHP variable without losing the syntax highlight. I would also like for when it is put in as a variable, it will be shown as a normal string not HTML code.

Is there a way like:

```
<?php

    $var = 

?>

HTML GOES HERE

<?php

    ;

    echo $var;

?>
```

I know my code here doesn't make sense, but it's just to describe the situation.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is strictly up to your editor.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php. What you need is an editor plugin though

Answer (score 2):

If the code is very long - say a menu div or something, you can use include. It won't give you a variable to use, but the result is the same.

```
<?php
include file_with_my_code.php;
?>
```

In file_with_my_code.php (doesn't have to be .php, .html works just fine as well) you simply paste the code as if you were creating a standalone html file.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it!

```
$var = <<<HTML
<HTML GOES HERE>
HTML;
```